# How can I prevent prettier from removing eslint standardJS comments?

Tags: eslint, prettier, standardjs

[StandardJS](https://standardjs.com/) (based on eslint) uses special comments like

```
function ClassName () { // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
```

That can not be broken down to the next line - even with long ClassNames. How can I prevent prettier from breaking the comment to the next line?

Answer (score 1):

Based on this [discussion](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/2273)
It's in the core formatting functionality and is not going to be changed without a big rewrite.

So for now your best bet is:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
function ClassName () {
```